# Prove that $\mathcal F_\tau$ is a $\sigma -$algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\{\mathcal F_t\},\mathbb P)$ a probability filtred space and $\tau$ a stopping time. I'm trying to prove that $$\mathcal F_\tau=\{A\in \mathcal F\mid A\cap \{\tau\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t\}.$$

I could prove that $\Omega ,\varnothing \in \mathcal F_\tau$, and that $\mathcal F_\tau$ is stable by countable union. But I have difficulties to prove that it's stable by complementary. Let $A\in \mathcal F_\tau$. So, $A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$. How can I prove that $A^c\cap \{\tau\leq t\}$ ?

Answer (score 5):

$A^c\cap \{\tau\leq t\} = \{\tau\leq t\} \backslash  (A\cap \{\tau\leq t\} $).

But $\{\tau\leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$  as $\tau$ is Markov moment,

$ (A\cap \{\tau\leq t\} ) \in \mathcal{F}_t $ as $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$

and finally $\mathcal{F}_t$ is sigma-algebra.

Thus $\{\tau\leq t\} \backslash  (A\cap \{\tau\leq t\} ) \in \mathcal{F}_t $  and it follows that $A^c\cap \{\tau\leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t $